# Angular material - Flex Layout and position issues caused by extra component tag

Tags: css, angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I'm working with Angular 1.5 using components.
The extra tag of the component is added to the html and causing the angular material 's flex layout to be wrong.

I've read the the replace:true is deprecated.

Anyone has an idea to handle these flex issues

Comment: Could you provide a CodePen, Fiddle, etc.?